# Android thumbnail view control with viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollbar

I'm developing an Android app.
I currently have a ViewPager that scrolls through a collection of images using fragments.

I'm trying to implement a scrollbar with thumbnails like the one in Google Play Magazines:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines&hl=en

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!